# How to set value of input field on select from form created using loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to set value of text box on change from select box created using jquery

```
 <?php for($i=0;$i<5 ;$i++) { ?>
<select  id="<?php echo 'aaa'.$i ?>" class="<?php echo 'aaa'.$i ?>">
                    <?php for($i=0;$i<5 ;$i++) { ?>
  <option value="1112" data-xyz="dynamic_value " data-abc="dynamic_value">dynamic_value</option>
            </select>
             <input  type="hidden"  class="<?php echo 'bbb'.$i ?>" id="bbb" name="<?php echo 'bbb'.$i ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"   class="<?php echo 'ccc'.$i ?>" name="<?php echo 'ccc'.$i ?>" id="ccc" />
                       <?php } ?>
                         <?php } ?>






            <script>
$('.aaa').change(function () {
var otherValue=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-xyz');
var someOtherValue=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-abc');
$('.bbb').val(otherValue);
$('.ccc').val(someOtherValue);
});
</script>
```

How to change value class bbb0-bbb5 in jquery without using loop in jquery

Comment: Why are you giving us PHP code? Just give the source HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not update the `class` names in `php-loop`, classes need not be `unique`.

To select `input:hidden` elements, no need to specify `ID` attribute

```js
$('.aaa').change(function() {
  var otherValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-xyz');
  var someOtherValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-abc');
  $(this).siblings('.bbb').val(otherValue);
  $(this).siblings('.ccc').val(someOtherValue);
});
```

```html
<?php for($i=0;$i<5 ;$i++) { ?>
<select id="<?php echo 'aaa'.$i ?>" class="aaa">
  <?php for($i=0;$i<5 ;$i++) { ?>
  <option value="1112" data-xyz="dynamic_value " data-abc="dynamic_value">dynamic_value</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" class="bbb" name="<?php echo 'bbb'.$i ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="ccc" name="<?php echo 'ccc'.$i ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$(this).next('.ccc')` won't work, since the `ccc` element isn't the next one. I think you mean `$(this).siblings('.ccc')`.

Comment: @Barmar Right! Have updated it.. Was curious about better approach if all the elements are in same level..without any parent.. `.nextAll('.css:first')` ?

Comment: That's another way to do it.